# Will limiting OR conditions in your SQL can fix SQL injection vulnerbilty?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection

Our website was reported as vulnerable to SQL injection and the developer who fixed this vulnerability was telling that they have to limit the OR clauses in the search criteria.

Previously users used to search with like 500 orders which is now limited. As he is saying as per SQL injection practice, you have to limit OR conditions in your SQL.

For example following log is showing those OR conditions, which as per his claim are limited.

Is it fine? and his claim is right?

**Edit**: Database is Oracle 11.2.

Conditions:

```
and (UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id0
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id1
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id2
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id3
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id4
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id5 
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id6 
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id7
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id8
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id9 
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id10
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id11
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id12
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id13
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id14
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id15
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id16
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id17
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id18
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id19
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id20
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id21
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id22
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id23
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id24
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id25
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id26
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id27
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id28
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id29
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id30
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id31
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id32
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id33
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id34
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id35
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id36
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id37
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id38
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id39
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id40
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id41
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id42
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id43
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id44
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id45
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id46
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id47
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id48
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id49
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id50
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id51
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id52
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id53
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id54
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id55
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id56
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id57
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id58
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id59
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id60
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id61
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id62
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id63
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id64
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id65
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id66
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id67
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id68
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id69
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id70
or UPPER(online_order_id) LIKE :param_online_order_id71)
```

Comment: The only safe way to prevent SQL injection is to use bind variables ("prepared statements"). The number of OR conditions is irrelevant for that (a really, really long list of OR conditions _could_ open the risk of a Denial-Of-Service attack depending on the DBMS being used, but not an injection attack)

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Why are you comparing online_order_id with 72 parameters?! (:param_online_order_id0 -> :param_online_order_id71)  This has a code smell. :-)

Comment: Also, that UPPER() function around online_order_id may cripple your performance, unless you have an index on UPPER(online_order_id). Is that conversion really needed?

Comment: As a_horse_with_no_name wrote, bind variables are the way to go. Those :param_online_order_idxx seem to indicate that you are already using them. How are those parameters populated? Can you include some code to show that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is Oracle database, we dont have the code of this application, since this fix was made by the vendor. And our users are complaining that they can not search with extended list of values which they used to do before like putting 300+ sometimes.

Comment: They fixed it but fixed it wrong. Rather than introducing an array type on the Oracle side and making *that* the type of one parameter, they've instead decided to pass each value (of the same "type") as a separate parameter.

Comment: The code you have shown is **not** vulnerable to SQL injection. However 300+ `OR` conditions could mean Oracle (especially older versions) needs a lot of time to optimize that statement.

Comment: Apparently he is saying that he successfully converted your query to prepared statements and now the issue is that the DB library only allows up to _n_ parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to see SQL injections in code performing this type of function, because the code puts together an in clause formed by concatenating values together (often with no validation).

As several folks have pointed out in the comments - it's likely that your developer fixed a SQL injection, but did it in a manner that is likely to cause performance problems and other limitations.   The developer is correctly following the general guidance to use parameterized queries (bind variables) but following that guidance blindly does not work well in this case.

The best way to fix this (as Damien_The_Unbeliever mentions) is to bind this to an [array type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28574) on the Oracle DB side - this requires only one bind, and will give you the best performance.  This requires the addition of an object on the DB side, so is more complex to implement.

The other option is to continue to use the in clause but ensure the code validating the values as they are being concatenated in - in the case of an order ID it's likely that you can just check that it is an integer.  This will not perform as well as the first option, but will handle larger number of orders more gracefully.